# Why PostgreSQL constructs incorrect brackets for daterange?

Tags: postgresql

Why query with inclusive upper bound:

```
SELECT daterange('2021-09-01', '2021-09-10', '[]');
```

produces the result with exclusive upper bound:

```
[2021-09-01,2021-09-11)
```

?

Comment: Why do you think those two values are different?

Comment: This confusess..

Comment: Oh no, a why" query. The answer is "because the developers thought that was the best design".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is here [Discrete Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE):

> The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, [). User-defined range types can use other conventions, however.

So there is no inclusive upper bound for a `daterange`. You can use `'[]'` but the parser will 'fake' it by pushing the upper bound up one date to make it work as an exclusive bound.